# What is recommended way to grant permissions using peewee?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

As far as I know from documentation, peewee can create tables from given models, e.g.:

```
database = SqliteDatabase(DATABASE)

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)

database.connect()
database.create_table(User, safe=True)
```

But what I haven't found yet, is recommended way to change permissions or grant access to the tables. I know that I can simply execute raw SQL like this:

```
database.execute_sql('GRANT ALL ON TABLE user TO ro_user;')
```

But I would like to know, whether there better/correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a fine way to do it. Peewee doesn't "natively" support creating `GRANT` statements. In fact, no ORM I've used does -- even SQLAlchemy which is very featureful [recommends](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3326/grant-user-privileges) the raw SQL way of doing it. Part of the reason for this is that permissions handling and `GRANT` syntax varies widely between different databases.

So your use of Peewee's `database.execute_sql()` is just fine.

One thing to keep in mind is if you want to dynamically specify the username and it's coming from user input or a source that's not 100% trusted, you'll want to escape it properly (in PostgreSQL, as a double-quoted, [delimited identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)) or ensure `username.isidentifier()` is True or something:

```
if not username.isidentifier():
    raise ValueError('bad username: {}'.format(username))
database.execute_sql('GRANT ALL ON TABLE user TO {};'.format(username))
```